# How to use hash table and array to create a lookup table?

Tags: sas, hashtable

The question is about calculating the minimum fee. I have a dataset called busfares,  which contains different station code, the destation code, type of fares. So much thanks to all of you if you wish to spend some time on my question.

The dataset looks like that

```
srt_na srt srt_id dest_na dest dest_id adult_pri student_pri child_pri eldery_pri
abcde  abc  1     abcde    abc   1        0       0           0         0
abcde  abc  1     bbcde    bbc   2        5       4           4         1
abcde  abc  1     cbcde    cbc   3        7       5           5         1
abcde  abc  1     dbcde    dbc   4        7       5           5         1
abcde  abc  1     ebcde    ebc   5        10      6           6         1
                                  .
                                  .
                                  .
abcde  abc  1     ooooo    ooo   91       30.5    20          20        1
bbcde  bbc  2     abcde    abc    1       5       4           4         1
bbcde  bbc  2     bbcde    bbc    2       0       0           0         0
                                  .
                                  .
                                  .
ooooo  ooo  91    abcde    abc    1       30.5    20          20        1
ooooo  ooo  91    bbcde    bbc    2       30.5    20          20        1
                                  .
                                  .
                                  .
ooooo  ooo  91    ooooo    ooo    91      0       0           0         0
```

The first question is how can i bulid up a lookup table using hash object which looks like that:

```
srt  srt_na srt_id
abc   abcde   1
bbc   bbcde   2
cbc   cbcde   3
dbc   dbcde   4
ebc   ebcde   5
```

The second question is how can I use four array to bulid the look up tables for different type of fares? The table should be look like that. And the row and column are representing different station name like row1 is representing abc, column1 is also representing abc as well.

```
adult   1   2   3   4   ...
1       0   5   7   7   ...
2       5   0   10  10  ...
3       7   10  0   5   ...
4       7   10  5   0   ...
```

Comment: The first table is the original dataset.

Comment: Because I want to use an array to create a summary table on different ticket

Comment: is it really called a report? Since I try to use the hash object to bulid the lookup table.

Comment: HOW are you going to use either the HASH object or the MATRIX (array)?  If you are not going to use them then perhaps you just want a print-out that humans can use like a train schedule?  Perhaps if you showed more code examples of what you are trying to do your question would be clearer.

Comment: I got it. So creating the hash table and array are trying to find the minimum bus fee for a specific customer(adult/child/elderly/student) based on their starting station and the destination.

Comment: Sounds like you want to perform a best path analysis?  http://support.sas.com/kb/57/738.html

Comment: No, I don't think so. But really thanks for your reply.

Comment: What do you plan to do with the planned 91x91 "martix"?  if you want to use it to find the fare for a particular from/to combination you can do that much easier with a merge or using a hash lookup.  If you want to use it for something else explain what that is.  Otherwise this really looks like an XY problem. http://xyproblem.info/

Answer (score 0):

You actually probably would be better off making your original table taller and narrower instead.  Convert the multiple fare type columns into multiple rows instead.  For example you could create fare_type (with values like 'adult', etc) and fare.

You could convert your current dataset by using PROC TRANSPOSE.

```
proc transpose data=lookup name=fare_type out=lookup2(rename=(col1=fare));
  by srt_na dest_na srt_id dest_id notsorted ;
  var adult_pri student_pri ;
run;
```

So if your customer data looks like this:

```
data cust ;
  input cust srt_na :$8. dest_na :$8. fare_type :$32. ;
cards;
1 aaa bbb adult_pri
2 bbb ccc student_pri
;
```

Then you could calculate the fare by matching your customer request data with the fare data on from station, to station and fare type.

```
proc sql;
   create table want as 
      select a.*,b.fare 
      from cust a
      left join lookup2 b
      on a.str_na = b.str_na and a.dest_na = b.dest_na
      and a.fare_type = b.fare_type
   ;
quit;
```

If you did want to create a hash object you could use that to find the price, no need for the array(matrix).  Again it would be better to have the lookup table taller.

```
data want;
  set cust;
  fare=.;
  if _n_=1 then do;
    declare hash h(dataset:'lookup2');
    h.definekey('srt_na','dest_na','fare_type'); 
    h.definedata('fare');
    h.definedone();
  end;
  h.find();
run;
```